# XSLT 2.0 Transformation on .Net 2.0 Framework

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, xslt-2.0

**Is .Net 2.0 Framework supports XSLT 2.0 Transformation and XML Schema validation in Windows 2000 Server?** *Since our client environment is Windows 2000 server and we need to implement XSLT 2.0 transformation on that.
We dont want to use 3rd party API's such as Saxon, XMLPrime, LightWeight XPath2 for .NET.*

If not,
**Is .Net 3.5 Framework supports Full XSLT 2.0 Transformation and XML Schema validation?**

*Please help me by providing suggestions.*

Answer (score 1):

XML schema 1.0 validation is supported [by the classes in Microsoft's .NET framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hdf992b8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). However XSLT 2.0 is not supported, `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform` only supports XSLT 1.0. If you want XSLT 2.0 you would need to use one of the third party options you have already ruled out.